# Redirect after output completed and file saved (not sure how to know when large PDF's fully saved)

Tags: tcpdf

I use PDF to generate a PDF and then save it to server like this:

`$fp = fopen( '$createdId.'.pdf', 'wb' ); 
     fwrite( $fp, $pdf->Output('example_009.pdf', 'S')); 
     fclose( $fp );`

A user will design something on our site then move onto the php page which calls the above code then I want them to redirect to cart so they can checkout.

Using

`jQuery(document).ready(function() {redirect() })`

doesn't seem to wait for PDF to fully finish before redirecting. I tried embedding a large image to pdf to test...I also tried just leaving the page straight away to make sure that the output and saving isn't actually happening behind the scenes after leaving page.

How should I make sure the page isn't redirected until the PDF is fully created and saved to server?

Thanks,

Joe

An overview of what I'm doing below - e.g building pdf obj, outputting pdf obj then hoping to redirect page after pdf completed

// INIT PDF OBJ
$pdf2 = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// SET DEFAULTS 
setPDFDefaults($pdf2,$pl,$resolution);

// ADD BG
addBackground($pdf2,$templated,$bannerInfo['backgroundColour'],$marginTop,$bleedTop,$bleedBottom,$bleedLeft,$bleedRight, $bannerWidth, $bannerHeight,$this);

// LOOP THROUGH IMAGES AND TEXT OBJECTS AND ADD TO PDF OBJ
drawObjects($pdf2,$json,$images,$sizeRatio,$countBG,$marginTop,$bleedTop,$margLeft,$this,$debugga);

```
 $fp = fopen( '/homepages/40/d449000017/htdocs/BannerPlanetMagento/js/bannercreator/savedBanners/'.$nSize.'/customer/banner'.$createdId.'.pdf', 'wb' ); 
 fwrite( $fp, $pdf->Output('example_009.pdf', 'S')); 
 fclose( $fp );

 $fpCustomer = fopen( '/homepages/40/d449000017/htdocs/BannerPlanetMagento/js/bannercreator/savedBanners/'.$nSize.'/print/banner'.$createdId.'_print.pdf', 'wb' ); 
 fwrite( $fpCustomer, $pdf2->Output('example_009.pdf', 'S')); 
 fclose( $fpCustomer );
```

var target = document.getElementById('loading-spinner');
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

```
// performRedirectAction()
```

});

Comment: Please show us your page code (narrowed to the relevant lines).

Comment: Hi, just added an overview, but it doesn't need to be complicated , my question would be the same even if it was just initiating the TCPDF PDF object, adding an image, 'outputting' then saving to server. Then wanting to know when i can redirect the page after the outputting and file save was complete. Thanks!

Comment: Why not redirect with header() ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was with a similar problem and I resolved this way I made the call that generated the pdf open a new tab.
And once the call was made it could not be reused, this prevents your code from being used countless times.
But what do you want or end with an exit () or has no choice besides using a solution similar to mine.
No one knows how to solve this, I did not solve it.